# I have a view from a longer query involving numerous joins, I want to further group and alter this view as shown in the body

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following view after running a long sql server query after joining a bunch of tables.

**This is the query:**

```
SELECT a.eventId AS [Event_ID],
    FORMAT(b.eventStartDate, 'd') AS [Start Date],
    dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR)) AS Categories,
    b.EventName AS [Event Name],
    d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName AS Teacher,
    d.Pay_Tier AS [Tier of Pay],
    CASE WHEN d.Pay_Tier = 'Tier 1' THEN '85' 
        WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 2' THEN '96' 
        WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 3' THEN '107'
        WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 4' THEN '117'
        ELSE SUM(a.totalpaid)*0.4
    END AS Pay_rate
FROM dbo.RetreatSuiteRegistrations a
JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEvents b ON a.EventId = b.EventId
    AND a.registrationStatusId = 1
    AND b.spacesAvailable > 0
JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEventAttributes c ON a.EventId = c.EventId
    AND c.attributeName = 'EVENT_CATEGORIES'
JOIN (SELECT t1.attributeId ,t1.EventId ,i.EVENT_TEACHERS
    FROM @attribute_table t1
    OUTER APPLY dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i ) AS MyTest ON a.EventId = MyTest.EventId
JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteTeacher d ON MyTest.EVENT_TEACHERS = d.TeacherID
GROUP BY a.eventId , b.eventStartDate , dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR)),
    b.EventName , d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName , d.Pay_Tier , Pay_rate
ORDER BY b.eventStartDate DESC;
```

**The view:**

```
 EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher | Paid  | PayTier
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Franco    1000    Tier 1 
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Jeff      1000    Tier 2
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Azeem     1000    Tier 3
  2        10/18/1995  MND       Bye         Rafa      15      Tier 2
  2        10/18/1995  MND       Bye         Ben       15      Tier 2
  3        10/19/1995  LMD .     Go .        Zoe       32      Tier 4
  4        10/20/1995  SND .     Zed .       Claudia   68     Tier 1
```

The problem is that I want to further group this Query by EventId so that for EventId there is just 1 row, and same with EventId 2 etc.
For example, rows with the same EventId should become a single row like this:

```
EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher     | Paid | Tier of Pay
   1     10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello   Franco,Jeff,Azeem  1000  Tier 3
```

I would like the all the teacher names to be shown in that row each separated by commas.
Since there different [Tier of Pays] for the `EventId` 1, I would like to select the highest one. so for `EventId` one `Tier 3` should be chosen. The `Paid` should be the single value so 1000 for EventId 1.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is modify your query:

```
select top (1) with ties . . .
. . . 
order by row_number() over (partition by eventid order by paytier desc);
```

If you want this ordered by another column, you'll need to use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Could you show the modification in my query by editing it and pasting it here? Cheers.

Comment: your answer partially works but I'd like the rows to show all the teacher names (franco,Jeff,Azeem).

Comment: @Azh588 . . . I don't know what your condition on teacher names is.  This question is "so that for EventId there is just 1 row".  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: check the body again, your solution moved the eventIds into single row so for example EventId 1 became 1 row, but it doesn't show the 3 teachers Franco, Jeff, Azeem it only shows Franco and omits Jeff and Azeem.